# Groupby Sum Equals 0 When Min_count=1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains duplicate column names. Now I am trying to combine the duplicate columns into a single column using the following command (the following dataframe is for demo only. it doesn't contain duplicate column names, but the same problem will occur with duplicate column name as well).

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
d['col2']=d['col2'].astype(str)
d['col1']=np.nan
d=d.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum(min_count=1)


the output is:
   col1  col2
0   0.0   3.0
1   0.0   4.0
```

But I expect

```
the output is:
   col1  col2
0   Nan   3.0
1   Nan   4.0
```

My hope is that, by using min_count=1, pandas will return NaN when the columns being summed up are all NaN. However, now it is returning 0 instead of NaN. Any idea why?

Comment: Note that I have set min_count = 1

Comment: `I have a dataframe that contains duplicate column names.` But your example dataframe doesn't contain duplicate column names. Can you describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: This problem exists even without a duplicate column names. @jpp

Answer (score -1):

This depends on your version number of pandas, when you set min_count=1.
If you have version < 0.22.0 then you would indeed get np.nan when there are less then 1 non-na values. 
From version 0.22.0 and up, the default value has been changed to 0 when are only na values.

This is also explained in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

Comment: It's the most up tp date version.

Comment: As said, because you have the newest version you get 0 instead of NA. If you don't want to see those zeroes, you could replace them by: df.replace(to_replace=0.0, value=np.nan, inplace=True)

Comment: I don't think this is changed in the newest version. The documentation only says it introduced this feature in 0.22.0, but didn't say it removed it. In fact, if you paid attention to my question, you will find that this only occurs when a column is string. Replacing it by 0.0 will corrupt the data as it may replace other 0s as well. This is a bug, and I have raised the issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23889 Thanks for your help.